My bootloader works on QEMU fine but no on real hardware
The bootloader is one of the hello world projects that i have found that in internet:
https://johv.dk/blog/bare-metal-assembly-tutorial.html
Before that I had tried to write some bootloader with nasm , fasm etc but none of them worked and just crash.
  format pe64 efi
entry main

section '.text' executable readable

main:
  ;; Recall that RDX contains a pointer to the System Table when
  ;; our application is called. So rdx + 64 is the address of the
  ;; pointer to ConOut, and [rdx + 64] is the pointer itself.
  mov rcx, [rdx + 64]

  ;; Now, RCX contains the ConOut pointer. Thus, the address of
  ;; the OutputString function is at rcx + 8. We'll move this
  ;; function into RAX:
  mov rax, [rcx + 8]

  ;; We already have the ConOut pointer in RCX. Let's load the
  ;; string pointer into RDX:
  mov rdx, string

  ;; Set up the shadow space. We just need to reserve 32 bytes
  ;; on the stack, which we do by manipulating the stack pointer:
  sub rsp, 32

  ;; Now we can call the OutputText function, whose address is
  ;; in the RAX register:
  call rax

  ;; Finally, we'll clean up the shadow space and then return:
  add rsp, 32

  jmp $

section '.data' readable writable

string du 'Hello, World!', 0xD, 0xA, 0

compile the hello world with FASM
fasm hello.asm hello.efi

I make FAT32 file system on usb and copy the executable file :
 mkfs.vfat -F32 /dev/sdb

mount /dev/sdb /mnt
mkdir -p /mnt/EFI/BOOT
cp -r hello.efi /mnt/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI
umount /mnt

I select USB flash drive in UEFI boot manager to be booted
Finally the result is crash and black screen when it goes to bootup USB.
Even when i go to /BOOT/EFI/ in UEFI shell and try to execute BOOTx64.EFI, the result is crash.

Welcome to the site. Please include relevant code, commands, etc, as text in code blocks within your question, not as images or behind links.

Possibly a stack alignment issue? The stack needs to be 16 byte aligned when calling a function. It is misaligned at the top of each function because of the return address. To realign it, try adding a push rbp at the top of the function and a pop rbp before the ret.  push rbp will subtract 8 from RSP and realign the stack to a 16 byte boundary.

I have downvoted your question because it doesn't have the code you tried as text.  Please [edit] your question and add your code, I'll then take back my downvote.  Without having seen your code, this could be a missing BPB (BIOS parameter block).

@fuz Probably not  a BPB issue since they are booting using UEFI.
